# Invoke list of methods by using reflection

Tags: c#, wcf, design-patterns, reflection

I'm using the publish subscribe pattern inside a WCF environment.

When I want to publish a message from the pub\sub service to the subscribers

i'm doing it by using reflection.

i'm invoking the methods one by one using foreach.

How can I do this operation async?

thanks

Comment: Why reflection? Post your code... Also, check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8383439/invoke-list-of-methods-by-using-reflection

Comment: I'm using pipe binding, I guess post is not working for that. am I wrong? for now I'm using Parallel.ForEach.

Comment: can you share your code?

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to run each method invocation asynchronously and don't care about return values you can just spin of each one of them on a new thread pool thread, for example using `System.Threading.ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(WaitCallback)`.

If you're in a more advanced scenario, there's the TPL (Task Parallel Library), Rx.NET (Reactive Extensions) and other more structured and capable ways of doing this.

Comment: I'm using Parallel.ForEach(), do you have a better solution? maybe which not using reflection?

Comment: For what my answer was intended, `Parallel.ForEach` works in the same way. However, it has little do to with how you invoke your methods, whether it be using reflection or some other dynamic technique. Is this was you're really asking; how to dynamically invoke methods?